Source for quote about love wanting the loved one to suffer
I recently listened to someone read a text (possibly in Greek or Latin originally, but they were reading a translation of it) on the topic of love.
The gist of it was that part of love is desiring to cause pain to the loved one – but not merely physical pain, even if in one passage the desire of a lover to sink their “tiny teeth” in the flesh of the beloved was used as an example. I remember it precisely for the uncommon reference to those “little teeth” (“dentini” in the Italian translation).
